# how to get Product id from order id

Tags: magento2, orders

i want to get products ids in Order by using order id,

i tried few methdods for it but none of them seems working

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());

}
```

can you tell what i am missing or how to get it

Comment: where is your order_id in code ?

Comment: order_id  is value like 00000002

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Product Id by:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId(000000171);
 $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        echo $item->getId();echo $item->getProductId();

     }
```

**[Answer Source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201651/how-to-get-all-the-items-using-the-order-id-in-magento2)**

Comment: getId -> is it product id ? as it seems something else

Comment: yes, its product id.

Comment: i just checked it should be getProductId for product id

Comment: You are right, edit accepted as well :)